# SVG through the jQuery.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In jQuery svg plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/svg) work with svg is performed starting from div element and creating new svg object inside of div:

> Attach an SVG canvas to a  with the following:

```
$(selector).svg();
```

Is it possible to connect with jquery to existing svg-object? If "yes" how to do that?

**EDIT:**
Suggested tip:

```
<body onload="alert('loaded');testSvg();">
    <div id="div3" style="border: solid 1px black; width:200px; height:100px">
        <svg id="svg3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function testSvg() {
        var svgRootElement = $("#svg3").get();
        var svgWrapper = new $.svg._wrapperClass(svgRootElement);
        svgWrapper.circle(30, 25, 50, { fill: 'red' });
    }
```

causes an error:

> 'TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'createElementNS': object is null or undefined' error...

why?

Comment: i suggest you break the edit out into a new question. i have an idea about how to answer it, but it would be too confusing to answer it here.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033939/how-to-create-jquery-wrapper-on-existing-svg-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It's described [here](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html#tips), although it's a bit difficult to find. If you're using inline SVG (e.g. you're not embedding SVG into HTML using an object tag, or an iframe), then the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var svgRootElement = $("#myExistingSVGObject");
var svgWrapper = new $.svg._wrapperClass(svgRootElement); // this is the equivalent of what is returned from the call to .svg()
})
```

Comment: is it required to be in 'ready' function? Can I do the same in the end of body section? I tried, doesn't seem like workable...

Comment: yes, you could put it in a script element at the end of the body section. because elements load in document order you must either do this, or wrap it in a document ready callback. typically, it is desirable to put your scripts in the head element, which is why most javascript libraries include a cross-browser solution for listening to the dom ready event. either way should work, though.

Comment: And the question: what is returned by 'svg()'? I used only 'svg' variable that is passed into 'onLoad' method used in .svg({onLoad:MyMethod});... How to use 'clean' svg()?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by 'clean' svg. The object that is normally referred to by 'svg' in jquery svg is a factory object that allows you to easily create SVG elements, e.g. svg.circle(...)