# How to create JQuery wrapper on existing svg-object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

In similar topic I've asked if that is possible at all (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006364/svg-through-the-jquery-svg), but when I tried to implement that:

```
<body onload="alert('loaded');testSvg();">
<div id="div3" style="border: solid 1px black; width:200px; height:100px">
    <svg id="svg3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></svg>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function testSvg() {
    var svgRootElement = $("#svg3").get();
    var svgWrapper = new $.svg._wrapperClass(svgRootElement);
    svgWrapper.circle(30, 25, 50, { fill: 'red' });
}
```

I've got an error:

> 'TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'createElementNS': object is null or undefined' error...

Why? How to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: In that question `get()` is not suggested - why are you doing this? `get()` without any parameters converts the jQuery object into an Array but I don't see the reason behind that here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get the first DOM element, not the array. Use an array accessor or `.get(0)`:

```
var svgRootElement = $("#svg3")[0];
console.log(svgRootElement);
var svgWrapper = new $.svg._wrapperClass(svgRootElement);
svgWrapper.circle(30, 25, 50, { fill: 'red' });
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/kJCAr/